# CListCtrl::GetSelectedColumn() function in C++ not working as expected in Windows 10 OS

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

We have been doing some development using the CListCtrl Class. Things are working fine in Windows 7 but it is giving some strange behavior in Windows 10 os. I am trying to achieve something very simple here.I have a function let’s say funSelect the code snippet looks like this

//this Function is trying to copy the selected column holding by the CListCtrl object

**funcSelect()**
{

/* The first Step where I am calling the GetSelectedColumn() function to get the selected column which is part of the CListCtrl class */

**int iselectedCoulmn = CListCtrlObj.GetSelectedColumn();**

// If no column is selected windows 7 will return -1 where Windows 10 is returning 0

//based on the value -1 the rest of the code is written. But in Win 10 it is giving as 0 . So the code is not hitting and creating problems

}

I did check all the settings like manifest file and it is using ComCtl32.dll version 6 properly Also it is using SDK Ver 10 and I have checked the VS2015 set up I can see all the SDK includes are properly set up. So all these things are in place.

**Can someone please throw Some light why this API GetSelectedColumn() is returning 0 instead of - 1. Has anything changed for this API for Windows10?**

**The correct behavior is it should get -1 when no column is selected. Even the MSDN documents say that. Is there any alternative way of achieving the GetSelectedColumn() but more in platform independent and generic way?**

**Any function or Code snippet will highly help.**

Also as an FYI in the manifest file we did introduce the compatibility tag so that it can call the native API, but even after that there is no change in GetSelectedColumn() return value. It still returns 0 instead of -1.
Just as an FYI the below has been added into the manifest files

```
<compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
        <application>
            <!-- Windows 10 -->
            <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>
            <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
            <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>
            <!-- Windows Vista -->
            <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/>
            <!-- Windows 7 -->
            <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
            <!-- Windows 8 -->
            <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>
        </application>
    </compatibility>
```

I will really appreciate if some can throw more light on this and if somebody has encountered the same issue then how did they resolve it. Any snippet or Function which one can do the job please let me know. I will really appreciate if I can get some reply at the earliest
Thanks - Yan

Comment: Which MSDN document are you referring to? I couldn't find anything that specifies the return value of `CListCtrl::GetSelectedColumn()` / `LVM_GETSELECTEDCOLUMN` in case that no column is selected.

Comment: Please show reproducible example [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)